# jmeter, selenium, chromeDriverConfig plugin throw Cannot assign requested address under Ubuntu

Tags: performance, testing, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to use these setup(jmeter, selenium, chromeDriverConfig plugin)  in order to run some scripts.
They are working fine under Windows10, but under Centos 7 (with correct drivers for that OS) I have got the following error in the logs:
`[1594929092.127][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)`

Whit that plugin, I can't pass any flags to the driver at the start.
How can I resolve that error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just ignore this error as the driver can be started/used normally:

[image]

I tried to provide `--whitelisted-ips` parameter and bind the chromedriver only to IPv4 loopback address and the error disappeared:

[image]

So if for some reason you cannot just ignore this error consider migrating to [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) and instantiating ChromeDriver manually providing relevant [ChromeOptions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html)